# Concatenate 2 Interpolation

Tags: angular-material, interpolation

I am new to this site and new to Angular as well.  I'm trying to combine/concatenate 2 interpolations.  Is that possible?  Below is my code:

```
<mat-grid-tile>
<mat-form-field *ngIf="item.controls.type.value=='DropDown'">                                     
<mat-select formControlName="label" placeholder="label">                             
<ng-container *ngFor="let option of dropdownData">                                                
<mat-option  [value]="'option.' + 'item.controls.field.value'">{{'option.' + 'item.controls.field.value'}}</mat-option>
</ng-container>
</mat-select>  
</mat-form-field> 
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work using the code below:

```
 <mat-select formControlName="label" placeholder="labelx">                               
                                        <ng-container *ngFor="let option of dropdownData">                                                
                                        <mat-option  [value]="option[item.controls.field.value]">{{option[item.controls.field.value]}}</mat-option>
                                       </ng-container>
                                      </mat-select>
```